Update Validation List on Sheet2 Using Data From ColumnA in Sheet1
I'm trying to add data from column A in sheet1, into a validation drop down list in a specific cell in sheet2. The length of data in column A will change depending on data retrieved for the day. My current code calls out a specific range (etc. "A2:A13"). How can I use Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to provide more flexibility in selecting the ranges from columnA sheet1?
Following are the current:
'Select and update new AccessionGroups

Sub Update()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheet1
Set WS2 = Sheet2

'lastrow = Worksheets(WS).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row (**Trying to figure out how to use this)

WS2.Range("E9").Validation.Delete
WS2.Range("E9").Validation.Add xlValidateList, , ,"='" & WS.Name & "'!" & WS.Range("A2:A13").Address
     
WS2.Range("E10").Validation.Delete
WS2.Range("E10").Validation.Add xlValidateList, , ,"='" & WS.Name & "'!" & WS.Range("A2:A13").Address

WS2.Range("E11").Validation.Delete
WS2.Range("E11").Validation.Add xlValidateList, , ,"='" & WS.Name & "'!" & WS.Range("A2:A13").Address

End Sub

I got this code from another site, to fit my purpose for this project. Why is there 3 comas for xlValidateList

You can use something like this:
Sub Update()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim validationRange As String

    Set WS = Sheet1
    Set WS2 = Sheet2

    ' Determine the last row with data in column A of Sheet1
    lastRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Create the range string for data validation
    validationRange = "Sheet1!$A$2:$A$" & lastRow

    ' Update data validation for the specified cells in Sheet2
    With WS2.Range("E9").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & validationRange
    End With

    With WS2.Range("E10").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & validationRange
    End With

    With WS2.Range("E11").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & validationRange
    End With

End Sub

Why are there three commas in xlValidateList? The Validation.Add method has several parameters, Type, AlertStyle, Operator, Formula1. The commas separate these parameters, and if a parameter is not needed, it is left blank, hence the three commas.

Thanks @Michal. I tried the suggested code, and it worked without any errors, but the validation list provides "'Sheet1'!A2:A" (literally) as a result. Did i miss something?

@mdatawolf  fixed, it was a typo, apologies.

The error message i now get is "Application-defined or object-defined error". Does this have to do with how we concatenate the data in Sheet1 column A into Strings?

@mdatawolf - what line is the error on? It works correctly for me.

When using the "Step Into" Debug function, the error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" shows up when it steps into "End With" right after the first "Formula:="=" & validationRange

Something was off with the initial workbook. I initiated a new workbook and the code worked seamlessly. Thanks dude!! Happy holidays to you!
